# Backbone event handler doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I have two views -- a layout view, which is top-level, and a new form view, which acts as a child to the layout and renders within it. I have one event handler in the form view, which is supposed to create a new instance of my model according to the data from the input.

Here's the layout view:

```
var LayoutView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: "#layout",
    render: function (view) {
        this.child = view;
        if (this.child) {
            this.child.remove();
        }
        this.$el.html(this.child.render().el);
        return this;
    }
});
```

and here's my form view:

```
var ResumeForm = Backbone.View.extend({
    events: {
        'click #create': 'createResume'
    },
    initialize: function () {
        this.template = _.template($('#new-resume').html());
    },
    render: function () {
        this.$el.html(this.template());
        return this;
    },
    createResume: function () {
        // getting values from template inputs and saving them to model
        var resume = new Resume({
            profession: $('#profession').val(),
            firstName: $('#firstname').val(),
            lastName: $('#lastname').val()
        });
        // saving a new model to collection instance
        resumes.add(resume);
        resume.save(null, {
            success: function (res) {
                console.log("POST resume id " + res.toJSON().id);
            },
            error: function () {
                console.log("Failed to POST");
            }
        });
    }
});
```

My form view renders within my layout view perfectly, but when I enter the values and click `#create` button, nothing happens -- neither saves the model nor logs any error mistake from my `createResume` method. I suspect that when rendering a form view in the layout view, the line `this.$el.html(this.child.render().el);` just destroys all event listeners, because if I add these listeners to layout view, it works.

Are there any ways to override this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Backbone's view `remove` function undelegates the events bound to the `el`.

From the [annotated source](http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html#section-160):

> ```
> remove: function() {
>     this._removeElement();
>     this.stopListening();
>     return this;
> },
>
> _removeElement: function() {
>     this.$el.remove();
> },
> ```

This has to do with jQuery [`.remove()`](https://api.jquery.com/remove/) function (emphasis mine):

> Similar to [`.empty()`](https://api.jquery.com/empty/), the `.remove()` method takes elements out of the DOM. Use `.remove()` when you want to remove the element itself, as well as everything inside it. In addition to the elements themselves, **all bound events and jQuery data associated with the elements are removed**. To remove the elements without removing data and events, use [`.detach()`](https://api.jquery.com/detach/) instead.

If you call `remove` before reusing the view, you need to manually call the `this.delegateEvents()` to re-bind the events from the `events` hash and re-wire any event the view was listening through `this.listenTo(...)`.

But the best way to re-use views, without calling `remove` which calls `stopListening`, you can use `setElement` which undelegates the events, and change the view element to the passed element, then re-delegates the events.

> ```
> setElement: function(element) {
>     this.undelegateEvents();
>     this._setElement(element);
>     this.delegateEvents();
>     return this;
> },
> ```

Your `LayoutView` would become something like this:

```
var LayoutView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: "#layout",
    render: function(view) {
        // if the view is different, make sure to undelegate the old view.
        if (this.child && this.child !== view) this.child.undelegateEvents();
        this.child = view;
        this.child.setElement(this.$el).render();
        return this;
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you a lot, Emile! That worked perfectly. I guess I should read the docs more. Now there's another problem -- when I click on `#create` button, it throws me the following error: `backbone.js:1907 Uncaught Error: A "url" property or function must be specified` but that's irrelevant to this question

Comment: @AlexNikolaev94 that error has to do with your `Resume` model not having a `urlRoot` property, or being inside a collection which have a `url` property.

Comment: it exactly does exist inside a collection which has a `url` property. shoul I remove it and add `urlRoot` property to model instead?

Comment: @AlexNikolaev94 I would have to see, but you can ask another question, and myself or someone else might help you.